# Entity framework date/time conversion for sqlserver

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I prefer working with `DateTime.MinValue`, even if I use SqlServer as backend.

Is it possible to make Entity Framework to convert from `DateTime.MinValue` to `1753-01-01` when saving entities and convert back to `DateTime.MinValue` when fetching them?

**Edit**: I do not want to use `DateTime?` (nullable value type)

Comment: You prefer `DateTime.MinValue` (and the SQL Server minimum `datetime` value) to `null`? Really?

Comment: Yes, Date comparsion is a tidier when comparing to MinValue than have to check for null everywhere. Same reason as why string.Empty exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SQL Server 2008 is an option, you could go with using datetime2 in your database which would allow you to store DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: Accepted the answer since no EF4 answers are avail. A datetype filter similar to `IUserType` in nhibernate would be preferable.